# Perform some actions when the Debug Flag is set

Tags: xcode4.3, ios5.1

i need to perform some actions when i am in the Debug mode, precisely, when i am in the debug mode, i want to add a button to my interface:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"Some actions, add button and assign an action, etc.");

#else
//Do another operations

#endif
```

However, this doesn't appear to work even with a simple `NSLog` just i put to test my debug mode.

Am i missing something? Thanx in advance.